# UIButton lazy to change state from normal to highlighted

Tags: ios, uibutton, ios7

I have a strange behavior. With Interface Builder I have defined the normal image and the highlighted image state for `UIButton` but if I tap quickly the button remains in the normal state (but the associated selector is call). The button change state only if I perform a long tap on it.

But if I tap quickly the image doesn't change and the button seems disabled.

If can help I have a view controller with a scroll view attached on it. On this scroll view I have attached a view (that is very long) realized with interface builder.

Ideas ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a feature of UIScrollView. It prioritizes scrolling instead of the button contained within. By setting delaysContentTouches = NO on the parent UIScrollView you should get nice, responsive buttons. However, you won't be able to scroll the parent UIScrollView while touching those buttons.

Comment: Wow I was so sure the bug was in my code but this fixed it perfectly. Thank you!